# Ubuntu pass Password containing '"' to sudo

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, sudo

I am trying to pass the password that contains `"` character as part of my password in a bash script to `sudo -S su`. I am running the bash script but I get prompt as `bash error: line1 EOF as end to " not found`.

Suggest some method to pass the password containing quotes successfully.

`echo "pass\"word" | sudo -S su`

prompt:
`bash error: line1 EOF as end to '"' not found`

I want to run the bash script without errors

Comment: Why not, instead, add the user NOPASSWD to sudoers? Note that you `pass\"word` will be available for anyone to see from your `.bash_history`. `bash error: line1 EOF...` that's an odd message, bash does `bash: line 1: stuff` format. Are you sure this is the exact error message that you are getting? Is there no space between `line` and `1` and no `:` after it?

Comment: It's odd, but it is reproducible with a new test user that I just created. The exact error message on my system is »bash: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file«

Answer (score 0):

This error is not caused by the quote in your password, but by the fact that both `sudo` and the shell spawned by `su` are trying to read from stdin:

```
$ bash -c 'pass"word'
bash: -c: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: -c: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file

$ echo 'totallynotmypassword' | sudo -S su
bash: line 1: totallynotmypassword: command not found
```

As suggested by user [KamilCuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamilcuk), it is better to create a `NOPASSWD` entry in your sudoers file.